# Java: PrintWriter with both encoding and buffer size

Tags: java, file-io, encoding

I need a *PrintWriter* that uses specific encoding and buffer of a user-defined size. I know how to do any of those:

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(
            new FileOutputStream(OUTPUT_FILE, false), 64 * 1024 * 1024));
```

or

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(OUTPUT_FILE, encodingName);
```

How to do both at the same time?

Answer (score 3):

Use a [`OutputStreamWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html) to specify **the target encoding** with the constructor [`new PrintWriter(writer)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter-java.io.Writer-), so it should be something like that:

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(
    new OutputStreamWriter(
        new BufferedOutputStream(
            new FileOutputStream(OUTPUT_FILE, false), 64 * 1024 * 1024
        ), encodingName
    )
);
```